How to select/unselect items in the legend using echarts4rProxy?
I am trying to select/unselect items in an echarts4r legend, using echarts4rProxy, and I can’t seem to get it to work.
In the minimal reproducible example, which is based on this simple example where dataZoom can be updated using echarts4rProxy, I have tried using:
e_dispatch_action_p("legend", legendUnSelect = "versicolor")
e_legend_unselect("versicolor")
e_legend(selected = list("setosa" = T, "versicolor" = F, "virginica" = T))

None of these worked.
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(8, echarts4rOutput("chart")),
    column(4, actionButton("go", "Go"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderEcharts4r({
    iris |>
      group_by(Species) |>
      e_charts(Sepal.Length) |>
      e_scatter(Sepal.Width) |>
      e_datazoom()
  })
  
  observe({
    
    req(input$go)
    
    echarts4rProxy("chart") |>
      e_dispatch_action_p("legend", legendUnSelect = "versicolor")
    
    echarts4rProxy("chart") |>
      e_dispatch_action_p("dataZoom", startValue = 1, endValue = 2) 

    echarts4rProxy("chart") |>
      e_legend(selected = list("setosa" = T, "versicolor" = F, "virginica" = T))

    echarts4rProxy("chart") |>
      e_legend_unselect("versicolor")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


You have used the arguments wrong, use echarts4rProxy("chart") |>       e_dispatch_action_p("legendUnSelect", name = "versicolor").
